# Why did I lose reputation for "removed: Password Authentication"?

Tags: support, reputation

In the reputation tab for my SO account I have a row that says:

```
-2 Feb 27
-2 00:01    removed    Password Authentication
```

Why did I lose 2 reputation for *Password Authentication*?

Here's a screenshot.
[image: screenshot of reputation tab]

Comment: Perhaps a post you had suggested an edit to was removed by Roomba.

Comment: @JeanneDark Not quite, perhaps I'm mistaken, but I do not see `Password Authentication` in that list.

Comment: @wcarhart it does answer your question - but it is not obvious.  "Password Authentication" is not a message, it is the title of a question.  You suggested an edit to it as some point in the past and the question got deleted on Feb 27th.  The relevant section is: `a post where you had successfully suggested an edit has been deleted (reputation page shows the cause as "removed"): -2`

Comment: Your [approved suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/24044799) effectively got reversed when the question you edited got roomba'd 9 days ago...